# Casting pointer-to-member of derived class to pointer-to-member of base class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, member

I know that it is terrible practice, but still wondering.
When I'm casting pointer-to-member of derived class to pointer-to-member of base class as follows:

```
struct A
{
    void foo(){};
};

struct B: A
{
    void bar(){}
};

int main()
{
    void (A::*p)() = (void (A::*)())(&B::bar); // shit
    return 0;
}
```

compiler (clang, gcc) gives me error, and that's correct!
But if I declare typedef like this:

```
struct A
{
    typedef void (A::*handler)();
    void foo(){};
};

struct B: A
{
    void bar(){}
};

int main()
{
    void (A::*p)() = (A::handler)(&B::bar);
    return 0;
}
```

It's okay and compiles. Why does this typedef affect compilation? I suspect this should result in UB. Does it make program well-formed?

Comment: Your first version compiles with gcc. link here http://cpp.sh/6owv .

Comment: @rakeshdn, my bad.. The question is irrelevant now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There’s [nothing broken here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59228652/8586227) so long as any `A*` (or `A&`) used with it really refers to a `B`.