# Why is it allowed to static_cast a method of a derived class to a method of the base class?

Tags: c++, methods, language-lawyer, function-pointers, static-cast

example

```
struct B1{int x; void f(){x = 1;}};
struct D : B1{int x; void f(){B1::x = 2;}};

using Dmp = void(D::*)();
using B1mp = void(B1::*)();

int main()
{
    Dmp dmp = &D::f;
    D d;
    (d.*dmp)(); // ok

    B1mp b1mp = static_cast<B1mp>(dmp); // hm, well that's weird
    B1 b1;
    (b1.*b1mp)();

    dmp = &B1::f; // ok
}
```

And this example will compile and run just fine, and no problem will arise. But wait, now I'm going to use `D::x` in `D::f`, and now -- anything can happen at runtime.

Yes, you can also `static_cast` a pointer to the base to a pointer to a derived.

```
static_cast<D*>( (B1*)0 )
```

But here you can use RTTI to check the types, or just use `dynamic_cast` if possible.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior even though `D::f` doesn't use any other `D` members. Writing `b1.*b1mp` to get a member that doesn't exist in the object is invalid, no matter what the definition of the member.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `static_cast` allows a number of things that might be used in "unsafe" ways, like converting `void*` to another object pointer type, converting `Base*` to `Derived*`, and this one.

Although `static_cast` can be thought of as "relatively safe" compared to `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast`, it's still a cast. And like all casts, it represents a request to ignore some of the type system's safety requirements, with the programmer then responsible for using it carefully and correctly.

Comment: *with the programmer then responsible for using it carefully and correctly.* This is where things go terribly wrong. In the whole programing spectrum.

Comment: @vini If we could only have a completely safe, supremely versatile, and exceedingly expressive language which lent itself to efficient implementation and pleasant use.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
void f(B *b) {
  static_cast<D*>(b)->d_method();
  b->static_cast<void (B::*)()>(&D::d_method)();
}
```

you assume that `b` is a `D` to exactly the same degree in each case.  Being able to cast the pointer-to-member allows a **caller** to nominate any function from *any* derived class when passed to a function that expects a pointer-to-member for the base.

Comment: `b` and `static_cast<D*>(b)` have different address, but when casting a pointer to a method no offsetting is done, making it UB.

Comment: @Adler: That’s not my reading of [expr.static.cast/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12.note-2) (and its referenced [expr.mptr.oper]/4).  You can [see the adjustment](https://www.godbolt.org/z/ZxUzBy) for a pointer to data member; pointers to member functions are more complicated but do store an offset for `this`.